# Hosting an APP to accept requests parameters and return a response back

Tags: json, post, heroku, get, restful-architecture

I have a application hosted on some site say "www.myapp.com" which makes a request to another application(say compute_app) hosted somewhere else by passing few parameters and then the compute_app does some computation and returns the data back to primary app.

Say I  need to implement two operations : Addition and Decrement in compute_app.
Addition : This operation would need say 2 numbers and output is 1 number
Decrement : This operation needs only 1 number as input and result is the decremented number by some constant value

Let's assume compute_app is hosted at "www.heroku.com/compute_app"

Now basically I need to pass a string "add/dec" along with 2/1 numbers from "www.myapp.com" to "www.heroku.com/compute_app" which does the computation and the result is returned back to "www.myapp.com"

How should I go about designing this by making USE of GET/POST Requests.

The example that I took here is figurative.

Basically I am in need of doing REST API calls from my "myapp" to a externally hosted app (compute app- which does some data pre-processing) and then it actually makes the REST call to Servers serving LIVE data.

So control flow is like:
myapp(raw data)---->compute_app(pre-processing & make call to REST servers) .
Now Rest Servers------>return JSON response to compute_app(it again does pre-processing) and then--->return data to myapp.

myapp = ChatBot

compute_app= 3rd party app for writing Java/PHP code for preprocessing bcoz the framework doesn't allow me to write any scripting code.

Comment: why do you need to pass the data to a separate app to do the calculations?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon actually the example that I took here is figurative.

Please check updated question.

Comment: Can anyone please share views on this?